# Data Explorer page keeps freezing Chrome and Firefox

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, data-explorer

On Firefox 29.0 when I visit https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/209394, the browser comes to a grinding halt and does not recover.

On Chrome 35.0.1916.153 when I visit the same page the tab also grinds to a halt permanently until closed.

In both case the page loads, then the syntax highlighting loads, then at some point after that it freezes, pegging the CPU at 100%.

This problem is 100% reproducible, for me at least. I was working on the query and it was fine with an occasional unresponsive script. Then I created a permalink and the problem has been happening since.

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-bit

I have no plugins or add-ons for either browser.

Comment: The problem appears to be the complexity of the Flot JS work. I get told that the script has become unresponsive. Additionally, the graph has a lot of vectors/drawings on it. The query involves > 22,500,000 results, so it makes sense that it's overloading the browser.

Comment: @Haney I didn't even realize there was a graph. Is that new? It's not really a graph-appropriate query.

Comment: It also kills IE11. Must say, very impressive!

Comment: @Haney once upon a time, results were limited (think to 5000) why was it removed? There's really no point returning millions of rows back in my opinion.

Comment: It limits the results to 50,000 but the plotted data is all over the place.

Comment: @Haney Maybe a "do not plot" check box (and associated url parameter) might be a good idea -- at least the url parameter as a workaround to access the page if it gets stuck.

Comment: No repro on IE11 @ShadowWizard but that is maybe because the queryresults are now coming from the cache...

Comment: I mean I could have a `do not plot` checkbox but it isn't really going to help you avoid clicking on the query originally and getting JS-bombed. I feel like this is a one off and the originator of the post should exercise caution in creating crazy plots. Another option is to make plotting default to off and have to select it, but I feel like that would upset at least a good portion of the SEDE users. :)

Comment: @Haney As the originator of said query I disagree. I didn't want the plot in the first place, it's not really a plot-able query, but now I'm locked out of editing it because the inappropriate plot that I do not (and will not) want is blocking the page... kinda stinky UX (not that the plot isn't cool when it's desired). I can't continue work on that query without copying + pasting it into a new one (which currently I can only do on Chrome by clicking inspect in the window before it freezes... probably not what you were going for).

Comment: So maybe a `plot` checkbox would be useful? I feel like the community would need to discuss it and come to a consensus as it'd be a fairly decent change to SEDE. Granted, I fully see your point @JasonC and agree with you - crappy experience currently on this page.

Comment: @Haney Do you think I should start a new specific feature request topic?

Comment: I definitely would.

Comment: @Jason so you start new feature request asking to add a "do not plot" checkbox to Data Explorer?

Comment: @Haney guess this one can be marked [meta-tag:status-bydesign] then...

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'm working on it. Demands, demands!

Comment: Take your time @Jason, just want to make sure it won't slip through. :-)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236770/ability-to-disable-sede-plot-for-a-query-link-before-the-query-is-run

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [status-by-design](/questions/tagged/status-by-design). The rendering of the graphical plot is causing the crashes/delays due to a ton of vectors / data points in this query. Note that I'm only saying it's by design, **not** that it's good design. Welcoming any feature requests, as always. ;)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236770/ability-to-disable-sede-plot-for-a-query-link-before-the-query-is-run

Comment: I like this, it's a much better way of using my browser's 'close' button, I merely have to use a bookmark now :)